Not able to playback audio file saved with capacitor-voice-recorder
I am trying to utilize capacitor-voice-record library to:

Record audio
Play the audio locally before sending data to the server
Send audio file to the server

Here's the current code:
In angular service
startRecording = ()=> {
        try {
            return VoiceRecorder.requestAudioRecordingPermission().then((result: GenericResponse) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    return VoiceRecorder.startRecording()
                } else {
                    return Promise.reject('Permission denied');
                }
            })
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    }

stopRecording = async () => {
        console.log("stopRecording");
        let result = await VoiceRecorder.stopRecording();

        let blob = base64StringToBlob(result.value.recordDataBase64, result.value.mimeType);
        let data_text = await blob.text();
        let extension = mime.getExtension(result.value.mimeType);
        let write_result = await Filesystem.writeFile({
            path: `temp.${extension}`,
            data: data_text,
            directory: Directory.External,
            encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
        });
        let uri = write_result.uri;

        return uri;
    }

At this point I tested the locally stored file. Sent the file to PC and tried to playback the audio but audio player gives corrupted or codec error (note tried multiple audio players). While .aac file downloaded from the internet works absolutely fine.
What have I tried till now:

Tried storing data as shown above
Tried forcing the extension to be .aac instead of .adts that mime.getExtension suggests
Tried storing base64 data directly
Tried storing data:${result.value.mimeType};base64,${result.value.recordDataBase64}

None of these have worked. I think the issue maybe with the audio encoding but its just a guess.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
